# How to return the id of max(id) used in group by within LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, linq

Here's my target query:

```
WHERE 
    WorktypeWorkID in 
    (
        SELECT WorktypeWorkID from (
            SELECT WorktypeWorkID, MAX(LevelID) AS MaxLevelID
            FROM [WorktypesWorksLevels]
            GROUP BY WorktypeWorkID
        ) AS p
        WHERE MaxLevelID != 3
    )
```

And I need to do the same on LINQ (query notation), but not sure what's the correct way. Here's my attempt:

```
where (from t in ctx.WorktypesWorksLevels
      group t by t.WorktypeWorkID into g
      select new
      {
          WorktypeWorkID = g.WorktypeWorkID,
          MaxLevelID = g.Max(x => x.WorktypeWorkID)
      })
```

which lead to error and don't allow the "contains" (i.e. in).

Comment: C# is a language of types. What type is `g` in `g.WorktypeWorkID`? Why would you think it has that property? Try `g.Key` instead. Also, `g.Max(x => x.WorktypeWorkID)` appears to be an error - shouldn't it be `x.LevelID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following condition:

```cs
where (from t in ctx.WorktypesWorksLevels
      group t by t.WorktypeWorkID into g
      select new
      {
          WorktypeWorkID = g.Key,
          MaxLevelID = g.Max(x => x.WorktypeWorkID)
      } into s
      where s.MaxLevelID != 3
      select s.WorktypeWorkID).Contains(x.WorktypeWorkID)
```

It is direct translation of your SQL. But looks like everything can be simplified if more details will be added to the question: entities with navigation properties and full SQL query.